# How to connect to an FTP server

Tags: nautilus, ftp, filemanager

Previously,

We could connect to a file server in nautilus by clicking on the Files button in the menu bar, but in Ubuntu 16.10 i can not see it.

Where is he, because it was a great stuff

Comment: You just have to create a new network location, add your FTP credentials, and bam, it'll show up on the left side of the Nautilus window.

Comment: Alternatively to using nautilus, I like `filezilla` for ftp uses quite a lot.

Comment: @Fiximan you are right, i like nautilus for his simplicity but filezilla is more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a Nautilus window.
2. Press Ctrl + L to access the address bar
3. Introduce your FTP address: `ftp://user@server`. For example, `ftp://loved.by.Jesus@192.68.35.122`. **Note:** For FTP over SSL/TLS use `ftps://` instead.

In case that password is needed, Nautilus will prompt a dialogue window.